# Regex - Don't allow uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently validating a username on the frontend (Vuetify) as well as on the backend (Laravel), how would you add a check into this `Regex` to exclude uppercase characters:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$
```

Instead of `\w` (**Word** - Matches any word characters (alphanumeric & underscore)) I've tried something like this but it still allows uppercase characters:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][a-z0-9_.]{0,29}$
```

The desired result in these strings validate:

- riegiejeyaranchen
- riegie.jeyaranchen
- _riegie.jeyaranchen
- riegie._.jeyaranchen
- riegie.___.wewsd

and these fail:

- Riegie.Jeyaranchen
- .riegie
- riegie..jeyaranchen
- riegie.
- Riegie

Comment: It would be easier if you also explain what exactly you want to allow.

Comment: Please add sample strings. Also this is for JS or PHP?

Comment: why don't you just lowercase them? `strtolower($username);` Don't nag the user.

Comment: @MarkusZeller you see I would like to validate on the frontend while users typing their username, after is passed on the frontend I will also validate on the backend using the same Regex

Comment: I tested your regex on https://regexr.com/ i don't see any problem. Have you tried to check it over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_.]{1,28}$
```

which will meet your requirements. The `[^\W]` allowed for any alphanumeric character, or underscore, before the 29 character check. That also is a double negative, easier to write, `\w`.

You can see it function here, https://regex101.com/r/Bh6Tbd/2/, compared to https://regex101.com/r/Bh6Tbd/3/.

Comment: It still passes when you just type ```Riegie``` but it should fail, I don't want to allow any uppercase characters

Comment: @DenissMuntjans `Riegie` does not match. Please see demos.

Comment: You also could use an `or` on your negative lookahead to simplify a bit. `(?!.*(\.\.|\.$))`

Comment: Dennis, this answer is sticking close to your regex but you could remove `(?!.*\.$)` and change `{1,28}$` to `{1,28}(?<!\.)$`, (`(?<!\.)` being a negative lookbehind) or replace  `[a-z0-9_.]{1,28}` with `[a-z0-9_.]{0,27}[a-z0-9_]`.